# Recommended method for fast, and safe server side image resizing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, imagemagick

I currently have working code using GDI (`System.Drawing`). But I am looking at converting this to use either `System.Windows.Media.Imaging`, or **ImageMagick**

My concerns are that this should not leak memory, should be thread-safe, multi-threaded and should provide high quality results. ImageMagick seems to provide all of these. However, `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` has been suggested as a 'cleaner' solution.

Do you know of any pitfalls with either of these methods?

*Are there any other options that I should be looking at?*

Answer (score 0):

I have this routine working for me

```
public Bitmap FitImage(Image imgPhoto, int Width, int Height)
{
  int sourceWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
  int sourceHeight = imgPhoto.Height;
  int sourceX = 0;
  int sourceY = 0;
  int destX = 0;
  int destY = 0;

  float nPercent = 0;
  float nPercentW = 0;
  float nPercentH = 0;

  nPercentW = ((float)Width / (float)sourceWidth);
  nPercentH = ((float)Height / (float)sourceHeight);

  if (nPercentH < nPercentW) {
    nPercent = nPercentW;
    destY = (int)((Height - (sourceHeight * nPercent)) / 2);
  } else {
    nPercent = nPercentH;
    destX = (int)((Width - (sourceWidth * nPercent)) / 2);
  }

  int destWidth = (int)Math.Round(sourceWidth * nPercent);
  int destHeight = (int)Math.Round(sourceHeight * nPercent);

  Bitmap newPhoto = new Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
  Graphics newgrPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(newPhoto);
  newgrPhoto.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic; 
  newPhoto.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution, imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);

  newgrPhoto.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;

  var attr = new ImageAttributes();
  attr.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);

  newgrPhoto.DrawImage(imgPhoto,
      new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight),
      sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight,
      GraphicsUnit.Pixel,
      attr
   );

  newgrPhoto.Dispose();

  return newPhoto;
}
```

Might not do exactly what you want but you'll get the general idea. Its used in a multi threaded environment and doesn't leak.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I'm using already. However, I believe that there are warnings against using GDI in a server environment. Also, the resize happens on a single thread so is not so good for larger images.

Comment: Ouch sorry didn't realize. Shall I delete this answer? Don't know what is usual here :-)